# Azure - multiple virtual network gateways?

Tags: vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn

Within Azure, can a single virtual network have two gateways, one for devices that are policy based, and the other for route based? If so, how?

As to why I'm asking: I need to connect a legacy network in a hosted data center that only provides a Cisco VPN tunnel that is static only. Now I can't do vnet to vnet connections.

This should be basic, but I'm having a heck of a time finding the answer.

Comment: AFAIK you can't have multiple gateways and you can only do multi site with dynamic gateways. It might be something that is coming in the new Resource Manager portal or via new PS commands but not as yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't an answer to the general use case there is a way to set up Azure to Azure VPN links which don't require the dynamic route based functionality.

1. Define the two virtual network gateways using the policy based option.
2. Define the two 'local network gateways' using the same IP addresses / names as the virtual gateways above.
3. Define the connections using the *site-to-site (ipsec)* options.

Answer (score 2):

As Drifter104 mention, you can connect multiple sites to the same VNet, but only through the same gateway (see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-multi-site/)), you can't have multiple gateways on a single VNET. This is true currently both in Classic and ARM deployments.